# VB.net : how to close a form instantly?

Tags: vb.net-2010

i have this code on a form :

```
Function f1 as boolean

Try
   ------------
   -----------
    if condition
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if
Catch ex as Exception
   Me.close
End try

End function


Private sub s1

if f1 then

   instruction 1
else
   instruction 2
end if


End sub



But if an exception occur inside f1 , the instruction Me.close
```

doesn't close the form instantly , but after 
    instruction 2 on s1 sub is executed.
    How can i do to close the form instantly?

```
Thank you!
```

Comment: I'm sure that the `Me.Close()` will stops the execution of method (F1) instantly. You have to rephrase your post and also add `return` statement in catch block of F1 function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you opened the form you should do a `Me.dispose`

Remarks from MSDN:
The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when

> (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and
>   the form is not visible; and
>   (2) you have displayed the form using
>   ShowDialog.  In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to
>   mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Close()` doesn't stop execution. Since you've handled the exception, execution continues after the call to `f1`. If you want execution to stop, you have to allow the exception to continue on:

```vb
Function f1 As Boolean
    Try
        '------------
        '-----------
        If condition Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Close()
        Throw ' causes calling routines to stop executing as well
    End Try
End Function
```